# Make RVM ignore ruby patch level

Tags: ruby, rvm

Currently, my rvm based projects specify **rvm 1.8.7@gemset** in .rvmrc. This means that when I am installing the gemset of a new project, it will default to the latest patch level of 1.8.7, eg. ruby-1.8.7-p352 . Now I don't want to hard code '1.8.7-p352' in the rvmrc as other developers(or other projects) might have some other patch levels installed on their machine(from other projects) and also I don't want to install different patch levels of ruby on my machine.

Is there a way to make rvm ignore the patch level and just make it use any version of 1.8.7 installed - so that I can use one patchlevel of Ruby 1.8.7 across all projects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The thing you want to set up is called an `rvm alias`. See: http://rvm.io/rubies/alias

For your example the commands would be:

```
rvm alias create 1.8.7 ruby-1.8.7-p352
```

Comment: Running this command places a corresponding entry in the `.rvm/config/alias` configuration file.